# Runtime option Error when upgrade cucumber to version 1.2.4

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

I got this error when I am trying to upgrade my cucumber version from 1.1.2 to 1.2.4.
I am running on JDK1.8.

This is the code not working

```
RuntimeOptions runtimeOptions = new RuntimeOptions(System.getProperties(), argv);

    Runtime runtime = new Runtime(new MultiLoader(classLoader), classLoader, runtimeOptions);
    try {
        runtime.writeStepdefsJson();
        runtime.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("CucumberMain#run: Exception occured - " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (e.toString().contains("None of the features at")) {
            System.out.println("This should not be an error if feature file does not contains any scenario for"
                    + " execution or marked as ignore through tag " + e.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("There is some problem in cucumber execution. Error is: " + e.getMessage());
            for (int index = 0; index < argv.length; index++) {
                System.out.println("CucumberMain#run: Exception - argument#" + index + ": " + argv[index]);
            }
            // throw e;
        }
    }
```

And this is error output:

```
Error:(31, 41) java: no suitable constructor found for RuntimeOptions(java.util.Properties,java.lang.String[])
    constructor cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.RuntimeOptions(cucumber.runtime.Env,java.util.List<java.lang.String>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.Properties cannot be converted to cucumber.runtime.Env)
    constructor cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.RuntimeOptions(cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory,java.util.List<java.lang.String>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.Properties cannot be converted to cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory)
Error:(33, 27) java: no suitable constructor found for Runtime(cucumber.runtime.io.MultiLoader,java.lang.ClassLoader,cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions)
    constructor cucumber.runtime.Runtime.Runtime(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader,cucumber.runtime.ClassFinder,java.lang.ClassLoader,cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor cucumber.runtime.Runtime.Runtime(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.util.Collection<? extends cucumber.runtime.Backend>,cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor cucumber.runtime.Runtime.Runtime(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.util.Collection<? extends cucumber.runtime.Backend>,cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions,cucumber.runtime.RuntimeGlue) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor cucumber.runtime.Runtime.Runtime(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.util.Collection<? extends cucumber.runtime.Backend>,cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions,cucumber.runtime.StopWatch,cucumber.runtime.RuntimeGlue) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Error:(35, 20) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method writeStepdefsJson()
  location: variable runtime of type cucumber.runtime.Runtime
```

Comment: What are your glue parameters set to?  Are they pointing to step definitions? Do the glued paths exist?

Answer (score 0):

cucumber 1.2.4 has the following dependencies. Check your installed versions to make sure that they are up to date.

- info.cukes » cucumber-core [1.2.4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core/1.2.4)
- info.cukes » cucumber-jvm-deps [1.0.5](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.5)
- info.cukes » gherkin [2.12.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin/2.12.2)
- info.cukes » cucumber-junit [1.2.4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit/1.2.4)
- junit » junit [4.12](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12)

Optional

- net.sourceforge.cobertura » cobertura [2.1.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.cobertura/cobertura/2.1.1)
- org.mockito » mockito-all [1.10.19](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19)